# Mixed Poisson processes and independent increments

Tags: probability, statistics, poisson-process

In reading Ross' *Introduction to Probability Models*, there's a part on mixed Poisson processes which states

> Suppose that $L$ is continuous with density function $g$. Because
>
> $P\{N(t+s) - N(s) = n \} = \int_0^{\infty} P\{N(t+s) - N(s) = n | L = \lambda \}\ g(\lambda)\ d\lambda = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^n}{n!}\ g(\lambda)\ d\lambda$
>
> we see that a conditional Poisson process has stationary increments. However, because knowing how many events occur in an interval gives information about the possible value of $L$, which affects the distribution of the number of events in any other interval, it follows that a conditional Poisson process does not generally have independent increments. (...)

I don't understand why "it follows that a conditional Poisson process does not generally have independent increments". Can someone give a concrete example? And in what instances does it have independent increments?

Comment: In full generality, the generating function of a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$ is $E_\lambda(s^{N(t)})=e^{-\lambda t(1-s)}$, hence, in our case, $E(s^{N(t)})=E(e^{-t(1-s)L})$. Thus, if $N(t)$ and $N(2t)-N(t)$ are independent then $E(s^{N(2t)})=E(s^{N(t)})E(s^{N(2t)-N(t)})=E(s^{N(t)})^2$, that is, $E(e^{-2t(1-s)L})=E(e^{-t(1-s)L})^2$. This implies that the random variable $X=e^{-t(1-s)L}$ is such that $E(X^2)=E(X)^2$, that is, that $X$ is almost surely constant, that is, that $L$ is almost surely constant, qed. Concrete example: complete the computations ...

Comment: ...  for any nonconstant $L$, for example $L$ standard exponential yields $E(s^{N(t)})=\frac1{1+t(1-s)}$ and once again, $\frac1{1+t_1(1-s)}\cdot\frac1{1+t_2(1-s)}\ne\frac1{1+(t_1+t_2)(1-s)}$ in general, qed.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Did. Would you like to post your comment in answer form so I can mark it as the accepted answer?

I should add, I see that math works out, although I still have trouble understanding it conceptually. For anyone looking at this in the future, I'll also leave this link I found that argues essentially the same as Did's answer.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FKZDJaAmheg